# android play notification no sound sometime

Tags: android, notifications

Ok, some of my custom says that my APP **sometime** didn't play notification sound while received GCM push message...(Phone is samsung galaxy s3 and I'm pretty sure the phone is in RING mode, not in silent or vibrate mode)

I thought maybe they didn't select any file as notification sound, so I change my code to play default sound only.

Here's my code to play default notification sound :

```
    Ringtone r=null;
    try
    {
      Uri uri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
      r.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
```

So I get their s3, and see what's going on.

BUT, no any error message, no any error stack comes out, it just didn't play default notification sound...

Android device(s) I did tried :

- HTC Butterfly (exactly same module called DroidDNA in United States)
- HTC DesireHD
- HTC Desire
- acer A100(7" tablet)
- samsung note2

Above 5 devices are playing notificatoin sound well.

Why samsung s3 didn't playback notification sound **sometime**......

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why Samsung's android phone causes this problem, while HTC & Acer are working well

I did fix this problem with the following code :

```java
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_notify, tickerText, when);
if (allow play notify) {
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
}
if (allow vibrate) {
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
}
```

So I guess I can't attach my own notification sound to my App